# Capture the value of python -c "some code"

Tags: python

When using `sys.argv` on `python -c "some code"` I only get `['-c']`, how can I reliably access the code being passed to `-c` as a string?

Comment: did you try without '-c'?

Comment: sys.argv[0] is '-c'... so try `sys.argv[1]`

Comment: `sys.argv` will give you all arguments except the actual code, for example: `python -c "import sys; print(sys.argv)" something` prints `['-c', 'something']`

Comment: What I get is:
`python -c "import sys; print sys.argv"`
`['-c']`

Comment: Yes, that's all arguments except the actual code. What are you really trying to achieve here?

Comment: "how can I reliably access the code being passed to -c as a string?" - well, you're *running* it. Do you really need to manipulate it as a string, too? If so, why?

Comment: The reason is that there's code which is monitoring some statistics of a wide variety of scripts, some of which use `-c` to provide an entrypoint, and the name of the script is recorded from `sys.argv`. It's possible to change it, but it seemed weird that the code passsed to `-c` isn't easily available.

Answer (score 0):

As Imre's answer pointed out, the interpreter actually jumps through some hoops to parse the original commandline-arguments into `sys.argv`. The argument to `-c` is not part of what `sys.argv` contains, the *arguments to that argument* are;

On Linux and some other systems you can take the long route, use `os.getpid()`to get your interpreter's PID and the proc-filesystem to get your own commandline.

```
python3 -c "import os; cmdline = open(os.path.join('/proc/', str(os.getpid()), 'cmdline')).readline().split('\x00'); print(cmdline[-2])"
```

Yayy, a program that prints it's own code!

You can detect whether you are running `-c` by checking if `__main__.__file__` does not exist. Note however that `__file__` is also not there for interactive shells and `-m`-executions. You'll have to do some parsing on the commandline, which could get tricky.

Comment: Note to self: On MacOS, you probably need to call out to the `ps` utility to do the same deed. Use `sys.platform`

Comment: And in Windows, `ctypes.c_wchar_p(ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetCommandLineW())`.

Answer (score 0):

The option list starts after the code (which was passed as a string literal) according to the manual:

> Specify  the command to execute (see next section).
>   This terminates the option list (following options are passed as arguments
>   to the command).

It means that the name of the script will be replaced by `-c`. The

`python -c "import sys; print(sys.argv)" 1 2 3`

results

`['-c', '1', '2', '3']`

A possible solution is the usage of `inspect` module, for example

`python3 -c "import sys; import inspect; inspect.getsource(sys.modules[__name__])"`

but it causes `TypeError` because the `__main__` module is a built-in one.

Comment: Doesn't work even via `inspect.currentframe()`. The source of dynamically-compiled code is not added into `linecache`'s cache and is not available via the file system, thus cannot be retrieved by `inspect`. IPython gets around this for its snippets by giving them unique names and adding the source into the cache manually.

Answer (score 0):

Paste a copy of the code string after the codestring so it is available as sys.argv[1].

```
C:\Users\Terry>python -c "import sys; print(sys.argv[1])" "import sys; print(sys.argv[1])"
import sys; print(sys.argv[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

`python -c "import sys; exec(sys.argv[1])" "print 'hello'"`

`hello`